# Question on the hierarchy of named Ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

I was wondering how many named transfinite ordinals there are, and what the notations and names are, arranged as a hierarchy which ignores the different levels on a single level of Ordinals (ω+1, 2ω, ω^ω, etc), but rather the ones separately named, I know that it goes up rather high and has many separately named Ordinals, I just want to learn of more of them. And have my misunderstandings corrected.

ω
ε (Defined by where ω<sup>α</sup> = α or  ω<sup>ω<sup>ω<sup>ω<sup>ω<sup>ω<sup>ω<sup>...</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup> or ω↑↑ℵ<sub>0</sub>, if that is a valid notation) 
ζ
φ
Γ<sub>0</sub> (Feferman–Schütte ordinal)
ω<sub>1</sub>ck
ω<sub>1</sub>

Comment: Countably many: there are (at most) countably many constants, and the rules for forming new terms are few & finitary.

Comment: Clearly you're interested in systems of ordinal notations, which give names to transfinite ordinals. A good overview of the issues involved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal

Comment: 2ω is equal to ω, since the supremum of {2n|n<ω}={0,2,4,6,8,...} is ω